# Data cleaning using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python and data analysis, i extracted some data and want to clean it.

I have this data frame :

```
Name | Comment | ID | ***Location*** | time
```

However the location column has values that are not unified, for example some people have (**United Kingdom**), some have (**UK**) and some have (**united kingdom**) as their location.

I want to unify the location column, so that each country is identified by one name, Instead of having 3 different names for this country, I want to replace them all with one unique name.

Comment: it worked thank you, but what if the countries where a lot, i think it's time consuming to do the same all for these countries. is there any faster solution

Comment: If data is  a lot.  Extract country datasets of name and clean it into json or dictionary then use `map`. Or type it by starting from zero haha

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with keys are all the possible name you might see, and values are the one you want to convert to.

Ex:

`d = {'united kingdom': 'UK', 'United Kingdom': 'UK', 'uk': 'UK'}`

then

```
df['new_location'] = df['Location'].map(d)
```

your df will have a new column named `new_location` with these keys converted to `UK`

Comment: It worked thank you, what if the countries where a lot, i think it's time consuming to do the same all for these countries. is there any faster solution

Comment: You need to know what values you may be caught beforehand to build a dictionary, how do you suppose to convert it without knowing what you might see, right?
PS: set it as the answer if you find it's helpful

Comment: ok, i tried to find a dataset but could'nt find one with all possible countries with their reigons,cities/states.  i found out that some have (In hell) as their location.....i want to specify a condition that any other value other than those on the dictionary, should be 'Not Given', is that possible?

Comment: I see all the cities here (https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/list-of-all-continents-countries-cities)

Comment: And yes, you can loop over all values of `Location` and change its value if it's not in the list of cities:
`cities = ['Paris', 'Ho Chi Minh', 'Ha Noi', ...]`
`for i, row in df.iterrows():`
    `if row['Location'] not in cities:`
        `df.at[i,'Location'] = 'Not Given'`